# How to make p:fileUpload work?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

So guys , I've decided to do a college's "homework" using JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 5.0 and theoretically I'm at the end , but I have great difficulty uploading files and , after trying by the whole day , I decided to post. The problem is that the file does not go where it should go, but the method is performed and shows no errors and exceptions.

**page.xhtml**

```
<p:fileUpload id="msg"
              fileUploadListener="#{processoCtrl.handleFileUpload}" 
              allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(doc|docx|pdf)$/" mode="advanced" 
              sizeLimit="10485760"
              invalidFileMessage="Formato de arquivo inválido"/> 

<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>
```

**ManagedBean**

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
         ExternalContext extContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

         // I already tryed //WEB-INF// , \\WEB-INF\\ e \WEB-INF\ (who knows...)
         File result = new File(extContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/" + event.getFile().getFileName()));
         System.out.println("/WEB-INF/" + event.getFile().getFileName());

         try {
               FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(result);
               byte[] buffer = new byte[6124];
               int bulk;

               InputStream inputStream = event.getFile().getInputstream();
               while(true) {
               bulk = inputStream.read(buffer);
               if (bulk < 0) {
               break;
         }
         fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bulk);
         fileOutputStream.flush();
      }
      fileOutputStream.close();
      inputStream.close();
      FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("File Description", "file name: " +
            event.getFile().getFileName() + " file size: " +
            event.getFile().getSize() / 1024 + "Kb content type: " +
            event.getFile().getContentType() + "The file was uploaded.");
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
  } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         FacesMessage error = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), "erro.");
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, error);
    }
}
```

**Part of Web.xml**

```
<filter>    
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>
       org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
   </filter-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
       <param-value>51200</param-value>
   </init-param>    
   <init-param>
       <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
       <param-value>
           /var/temp
       </param-value>
   </init-param>             
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

PS : This was the last attempt by today after numerous! And This one seemed a lil "better" .

Comment: Please post your environment library, and the exceptions.

Comment: @wittakarn actually there are no Exceptions too... About the environment library, sorry but do you want me to post what I'm using? If so, it's commons-fileupload-1.3.1 and commons-io-2.4

Comment: You're uploading files in the `WEB-INF` directory (which is under the deployed WAR). Files are not meant to upload in the deployed WAR. Doing so would lose all those files whenever you redeploy the application. Try uploading them outside the deployed WAR to a fixed location.